# Apache incorrectly resolves requests with paths starting with /index.php/

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache2

In reviewing access logs I've noticed the below automated vulnerability scan for which Apache is returning a 200 status:

`POST /index.php/api/Uploadify/preview HTTP/1.1`

There's isn't a rewrite rule in place for this VHost and the file/URL doesn't exist. I can't seem to find an Apache directive for this and Google is convinced that I want to create this behaviour, not disable it.

Can someone explain to me to why Apache resolves this URL, and/or how to make it return a 404?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Apache's `AcceptPathInfo`

This behaviour is controlled with the `AcceptPathInfo` Directive in both Apache [2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) and [2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo):

> This directive controls whether requests that contain trailing
>   pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent
>   file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. The
>   trailing pathname information can be made available to scripts in the
>   `PATH_INFO` environment variable.
>
> For example, assume the location `/test/` points to a directory that
>   contains only the single file `here.html`. Then requests for
>   `/test/here.html/more` and `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect `/more` as
>   `PATH_INFO`.

By default

- core handler rejects `PATH_INFO` for normal files
- other handlers like mod_cgi, mod_isapi or mod_php generally accept `PATH_INFO`.

If you want explicitly disable this for all handlers, use:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

### PHP-FPM

The `AcceptPathInfo` doesn't seem to work with PHP-FPM e.g. if there's a proxy handler like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
<Proxy "fcgi://localhost/">
</Proxy>
```

In that case you could e.g. forbid access to all URLs containing `.php/`.

- Apache 2.2 [`LocationMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) & [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html):

  ```
  <LocationMatch ".php/">
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
  </LocationMatch>
  ```
- Apache 2.4 [`LocationMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch) & [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html):

  ```
  <LocationMatch ".php/">
      Require all denied
  </LocationMatch>
  ```

Comment: Thank you. A very clear and concise response!